# How to force wine to use my GPU?

Tags: wine, gpu, photoshop

I am running Photoshop 24 through wine64 and currently am not able to connect my GPU to wine to be able to use the program properly.

I do have `d3dx9` installed.

I have Ubuntu 20.04 installed.

[image]

wine Log:

```
05f8:fixme:process:SetProcessShutdownParameters (0000027f, 00000001): partial stub.
05f8:fixme:process:SetProcessShutdownParameters (0000027f, 00000001): partial stub.
05f8:fixme:heap:RtlSetHeapInformation handle 0000000000000000, info_class 1, info 0000000000000000, size 0 stub!
05f8:fixme:ntdll:EtwEventSetInformation (deadbeef, 2, 000028E2002D0450, 26) stub
0590:fixme:system:QueryDisplayConfig (00000002 000000000081E338 0000000001800510 000000000081E33C 0000000001800690 0000000000000000): semi-stub
05f8:fixme:ntdll:EtwRegisterTraceGuidsW   register trace class {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
0590:fixme:dcomp:DCompositionCreateDevice2 00000000017F4FE0, {5f4633fe-1e08-4cb8-8c75-ce24333f5602}, 000000000081DDD0.
05f8:fixme:ntdll:NtQuerySystemInformation info_class SYSTEM_PERFORMANCE_INFORMATION
05f8:fixme:thread:QueryThreadCycleTime (FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE,000000000081E778): stub!
05f8:fixme:ntdll:NtSetInformationToken TokenIntegrityLevel stub!
05f8:fixme:process:NtQueryInformationProcess ProcessHandleCount (0xffffffffffffffff,0x81ef80,0x00000004,(nil)) stub
05f8:fixme:process:SetProcessMitigationPolicy (8, 000000000081EF98, 4): stub
04d0:fixme:uiautomation:UiaRaiseAutomationEvent (0000621400996E90, 20015): stub
04d0:fixme:uiautomation:UiaRaiseAutomationEvent (0000621400C5DE30, 20015): stub
info:  NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 Ti:
info:    Driver : NVIDIA 525.125.6
info:    Memory Heap[0]: 
info:      Size: 8192 MiB
info:      Flags: 0x1
info:      Memory Type[1]: Property Flags = 0x1
info:    Memory Heap[1]: 
info:      Size: 48117 MiB
info:      Flags: 0x0
info:      Memory Type[0]: Property Flags = 0x0
info:      Memory Type[2]: Property Flags = 0x6
info:      Memory Type[3]: Property Flags = 0xe
info:    Memory Heap[2]: 
info:      Size: 246 MiB
info:      Flags: 0x1
info:      Memory Type[4]: Property Flags = 0x7
0648:fixme:system:QueryDisplayConfig (00000002 0000000016F6E4B8 0000000001800540 0000000016F6E4BC 0000000001800620 0000000000000000): semi-stub
0648:fixme:system:QueryDisplayConfig (00000002 0000000016F6E4B8 0000000001800540 0000000016F6E4BC 0000000001800620 0000000000000000): semi-stub
0648:fixme:system:QueryDisplayConfig (00000002 0000000016F6E4B8 0000000001800540 0000000016F6E4BC 0000000001800620 0000000000000000): semi-stub
0648:fixme:system:QueryDisplayConfig (00000002 0000000016F6E4B8 0000000001800540 0000000016F6E4BC 0000000001800620 0000000000000000): semi-stub
info:  DXGI: Hiding actual GPU, reporting vendor ID 0x1002, device ID 73df
0648:fixme:dwmapi:DwmGetCompositionTimingInfo (0000000000000000 0000000016F6EAA0)
04d0:fixme:kernelbase:PerfCreateInstance handle 0000000000B23AF0, guid {dd36a036-c923-4794-b696-70577630b5cf}, name L"WorkUnit|5|1524|1005|WebView2: CCX Comments UXP Internal", id 5 semi-stub.
04d0:fixme:kernelbase:PerfSetCounterRefValue provider 0000000000B23AF0, instance 0000000000B38808, counterid 1, address 0000621400B20F9C semi-stub.
04d0:fixme:kernelbase:PerfSetCounterRefValue provider 0000000000B23AF0, instance 0000000000B38808, counterid 2, address 0000621400B20F98 semi-stub.
01e8:fixme:file:CreateFile2 (L"C:\\users\\hutber\\AppData\\Roaming\\Adobe\\UXP\\PluginsStorage\\PHSP\\24\\Internal\\com.adobe.nfp.gallery\\LocalStorage/LOCK" c0000000 1 4 000000002B95F5D0), partial stub
0560:fixme:nls:get_dummy_preferred_ui_language (0x8 0x809 0000000026D2E5F8 0000000000000000 0000000026D2E5FC) returning a dummy value (current locale)
0560:fixme:nls:get_dummy_preferred_ui_language (0x8 0x809 0000000026D2E5F8 0000000000B09160 0000000026D2E5FC) returning a dummy value (current locale)
0560:fixme:nls:get_dummy_preferred_ui_language (0x8 0x809 0000000026D2E5F8 0000000000000000 0000000026D2E5FC) returning a dummy value (current locale)
0560:fixme:nls:get_dummy_preferred_ui_language (0x8 0x809 0000000026D2E5F8 0000000000B09160 0000000026D2E5FC) returning a dummy value (current locale)
05e0:fixme:file:NtLockFile I/O completion on lock not implemented yet
05d0:fixme:winsock:setsockopt Ignoring SO_RANDOMIZE_PORT
05f8:fixme:dwrite:dwritefontface5_HasVariations 00000000009D44B0: stub
05d0:fixme:winsock:setsockopt Ignoring SO_RANDOMIZE_PORT
05d0:fixme:winsock:setsockopt Ignoring SO_RANDOMIZE_PORT
05d0:fixme:ncrypt:NCryptOpenStorageProvider (000033A20026A228, L"Microsoft Software Key Storage Provider", 0): stub
05d0:fixme:ncrypt:NCryptIsAlgSupported Silent flag not implemented
05d0:fixme:ncrypt:NCryptCreatePersistedKey Persistent keys are not supported
05d0:fixme:ncrypt:NCryptCreatePersistedKey Algorithm not handled L"ECDSA_P256"
0378:err:sync:RtlpWaitForCriticalSection section 00000001486AE438 (null) wait timed out in thread 0378, blocked by 0024, retrying (60 sec)
0058:fixme:mountmgr:query_property Faking StorageDeviceProperty data
0524:fixme:file:ReplaceFileW Ignoring flags 2
04d0:fixme:process:GetProcessMitigationPolicy (FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF, 4, 000000000081E490, 4): stub
0524:fixme:file:ReplaceFileW Ignoring flags 2
0524:fixme:file:ReplaceFileW Ignoring flags 2
0524:fixme:file:ReplaceFileW Ignoring flags 2
0524:fixme:file:ReplaceFileW Ignoring flags 2
0524:fixme:file:ReplaceFileW Ignoring flags 2
0524:fixme:file:ReplaceFileW Ignoring flags 2
0524:fixme:file:ReplaceFileW Ignoring flags 2
0550:fixme:file:ReplaceFileW Ignoring flags 2
0550:fixme:file:ReplaceFileW Ignoring flags 2
0554:fixme:file:ReplaceFileW Ignoring flags 2
0520:fixme:file:ReplaceFileW Ignoring flags 2
05d0:fixme:winsock:setsockopt Ignoring SO_RANDOMIZE_PORT
```

[Edit]

This command is as close as I think i've got to getting it:

```
(base) hutber@hutber:~$ WINEPREFIX="/home/hutber/photoshop/PhotoshopCC" DXVK_STATE_CACHE=1 DXVK_VERSION="v2.1" VKD3D_DEBUG=1 VKD3D_SHADER_DEBUG="v2.8" WINEESYNC=1 WINEFSYNC=1 D3D_EXTRAS="v2" /home/hutber/.local/share/lutris/runners/wine/lutris-GE-Proton8-21-x86_64/bin/wine64 "/home/hutber/photoshop/PhotoshopCC/Photoshop-CC/Photoshop.exe"
```

I also wondered if this means anything?

`info:  DXGI: Hiding actual GPU, reporting vendor ID 0x1002, device ID 73df`